# How does coefficient change if we multiply a predictor by a constant in Lasso/Ridge regression

Tags: lasso

I found exactly the same question here

[Multiplying a predictor by a constant in Lasso/Ridge regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490376/multiplying-a-predictor-by-a-constant-in-lasso-ridge-regression)

and I copy paste below. However the answer in the link seems only state from the point view of implementation under R. What should be the theoretical result? I also asked in MathExchange.

If we multiply one of predictors by a constant $c$ in the regression set-up for all data points. What happens to the weights (or specifically weight corresponding to that predictor) if we are doing Lasso/Ridge regression?

In the case of OLS it is clear the effect would be the corresponding weight will be multiplied by $1/c$. Now if we assume $c=2$ and let's assume we are doing Lasso. If we multiply that corresponding weight by $1/2$ the mean squared part of loss function doesn't change and the $L^1$ part decreases. So you can say the minima of the new loss function will be less than the older one. But I'm not sure whether this implies anything about the individual coefficients or not. This might also depend whether $c>1$ or $c<1$.

Comment: Isn't the Lasso ordinarily carried out on *standardized* predictors?  Multiplication by a nonzero constant could then only change the sign of the coefficient estimate.

Comment: @whuber sorry don't get your point, could you give more detail? scaling on one feature will change all thing even after standardized.